# Запись в файл на Android Wear

Tags: java, android, android-wear

На Андроид часах  нужно реализовать запись информации в файл `*.txt`
Для этого я использую следующий код:

```
public boolean write(){

    boolean result = true;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = context.openFileOutput("text.txt",context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

        fOut.write(createJson().getBytes());
        fOut.close();

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = false;
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

А для чтения:

```
public boolean read(){

    boolean result = true;

    try {

        FileInputStream fin = context.openFileInput("text.txt");

        int c;
        String temp="";
        while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
            temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
        }

        fin.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        result = false;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Проблема в том что режим `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` уже `Deprecated` в связи с чем вопрос, как можно организовать чтение\запись другим способом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > [android fileoutputstream example](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20fileoutputstream%20example)
2. > http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

   ```
     File file = ...
      OutputStream out = null;
      try {
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        ...
       finally {
        if (out != null) {
          out.close();
        }
      }
    }
   ```

---

Ещё [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25320747/3212712):

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/text.txt";

try {
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath ));
    ...
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, это на телефоне работает, а на часах  java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: @KirillStoianov, посмотрите другой вариант из обновления ответа

Comment: Тоже пробовал java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/text.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), разрешение на запись есть!

Comment: @KirillStoianov, вы опечатались и у меня спрашиваете прописано ли у вас разрешение?.. Может, его надо в рантайме запрашивать у юзера.

Comment: то опечатка, разрешение прописано.

Comment: @KirillStoianov, какая версия ОС на часах?

Comment: 6.0.1,  я вот в доке нашел что альтернативой может быть контент провайдер, но хотелось каким то методом из описаных выше конечно

Comment: @KirillStoianov, с 6 андроида разрешения подобные надо запрашивать у юзера в момент совершения действия, а не в манифесте. Почитайте про `RuntimePermissions`